# how to redirect from www to non-www varnish

Tags: varnish

How do I go about automatically redirect any link of the type www.example.com to example.com.

I would like to do this for all link that hits the varnish instance (so i don't have to individually define the value for all domain that hits the server).

I tried using the following:

```
if(req.http.host ~ "^www\.(.+)$"){
    set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.", "");
}
```

It works, but the problem with that is it's hitting the right backend, but it's not redirecting. I understand from here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/redirect you can redirect to a url, but I am not sure how to get the "full" url from varnish to strip out the www and redirect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Comment: What you are doing there is an internal rewrite and not a redirect. In order to redirect you are going to have to send a 301 back to the client.

Answer (score 7):

Varnish does not have a native mechanism for redirection from `vcl_recv()`. Instead you have to throw an error from `vcl_recv()` to be caught in `vcl_error()`. This is because `vcl_recv()` doesn't have access to the response object. You can [read about how this is done](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRedirectInVCL). Below is my attempt at an answer in terms of your situation.

In `vcl_recv()`:

```
if (req.http.host ~ "^www\.") {
  error 750 regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.(.*)", "http://\1"); //Capture everything after the www. and place it after a http://
}
```

In `vcl_error()`:

```
if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 302;
    return(deliver);
}
```

Comment: This does not work with Varnish 4+. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

vcl 4.0;

```
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)$") {
    return (synth (750, ""));
   }
}

sub vcl_synth {
   if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = "http://www." + req.http.host + req.url;
    return(deliver);
   }
}
```

Comment: Generally it is recommended to include some explanation to what your code actually does rather than just posting it as-is - could you update your post with an explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for VCL 4.x.

First check it matches 'begins with' "www."
Then regex out the "www." from the start and set the new Location

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "^www\.") {
        return (synth (750, ""));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = 302;
        set resp.http.Location = "http://" + regsuball(req.http.host, "^www\.", "") + req.url;
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```