# Force WWW with Varnish and nginx

Tags: nginx, varnish

I'm trying to figure out how to force WWW in varnish for only one domain. I saw [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/441966/how-to-redirect-from-www-to-non-www-varnish) to remove WWW but I don't know how to translate it to force it.

Edit: To clarify, my nginx config was working fine. It was only after I added Varnish that this started happening. I found the culprit and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove this from my vcl file in Varnish.

```
if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?domain\.com$") {
    set req.http.host = "www.domain.com"
    return (lookup);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "if" without special needs. [If is evil!](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)
The right way is ...

```
server {
    server_name somedomain.com;
    return 301 http://www.somedomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.somedomain.com;

    # typical lines
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is for the Nginx config:

```
if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```